# Making a list of numbers from a textfile

Tags: python, sorting, file-io

I'm trying to make a program which bubblesorts a list of numbers from a text file. The file has one integer per line. I tried opening the file like so:

```
data = open(file).readlines()
```

but if I do this, the line breaks `\n` are included in the list and my bubblesort orders the number by the first digit only (i.e. 6 is after 19).  Here's an example of what happens when I run my program.  I first print out the unsorted list, then print the sorted list.

```
['13\n', '6\n', '87\n', '19\n', '8\n', '23\n', '8\n', '65']
['13\n', '19\n', '23\n', '6\n', '65', '8\n', '8\n', '87\n']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the elements of `data` into ints, as files are read in as strings. Before you do the conversion, it's probably also wise to remove the `\n` characters, which you can do with [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Using a list comprehension:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    data = [int(line.strip()) for line in f]
```

I added the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) context manager. It's usually good practice to use it when opening files, as it ensures that the file is afterwards. Also note that `readlines` isn't actually needed - iterating over a file provides each line as a string by default.

Actually, `strip` isn't even needed, as `int` automatically seems to strip whitespace. I might keep it just in case though.

```
int(' 13')    # 13
int('13\t')   # 13
int('13 \n')  # 13
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of integers:

```
int_data = [int(dat) for dat in data]
```

Of course, it'd be even better to do it one integer at a time instead of reading the whole file and then converting it to integers:

```
with open('datafile') as fin:
    int_data = [int(line) for line in fin]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend stripping the newline character and int converting.  You can do this in one succinct line with a list comprehension, but a for loop would also suffice if the list comprehension syntax is confusing.

```
data = open(file).readlines()
out = [int(x.strip('\n') for x in data]
out.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines() # give list without endline chars
numbers = map(int, data) 
# but be careful, this can throw ValueError on non-number strings
```

if you expect that not all rows can be converted to integers, write helper generator:

```
def safe_ints(iterable):
    for item in iterable:
            try:
                yield int(item)
            except ValueError as err:
                continue
```

and then use:

```
numbers = list(safe_ints(data))
```